# google maps requests are forbidden with a status of 403 after working very well for at least a day

Tags: google-maps, google-maps-api-3

I am using the Google Maps Javscript Api, v3 and everything is working well up to a point where the requests for the map images are forbidden with a status of 403. Usually the map stops loading after a period of time in which the page/session is open: it may be 24 hours, it may be more than 48h, I couldn't actually find a more accurate period.

Given the fact that we want to have a live website and a testing one – different domains, I generated 2 different keys, and I am loading them conditionally, but the html rendered is the one expected.

> var mapKey = VanillaRate.Domain.Settings.AppSettings.GoogleMapsApiKey;

and the script tag is:

> script src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=@(mapKey)&libraries=places" async defer

The usage limits were not exceeded, the referrer is well set.

The error appears when the map is zoomed and it's:

> Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 403 () - maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js/StaticMapService.GetMapImage?....

Since I couldn’t find any exact posted situation nor documentation about it, it is possible to be a timeout on google servers for security reasons and this is why the requests are forbidden for a session longer than a day?

EDIT: I forgot to mention that after refreshing the tab, everything works well. If it was indeed the usage limit, would the server respond with success after refresh? I've read that in this case, the map wouldn't work all day. Is that right?

Answer (score 0):

> If the response is still a HTTP 403 (Forbidden) error, the signature was not necessarily the problem, it may be related to usage limits instead.
>
> This typically means your access to the web service has been blocked on the grounds that your application has been exceeding usage limits for too long or otherwise abused the web service.

I find this answer on [google developer](https://developers.google.com/maps/premium/previous-licenses/articles/usage-limits#http403). There is no simply way to resolve this problem. Google recommended two solutions:

1. Reduce requests to the server;
2. Or, 'purchasing additional allowance for your Google Maps APIs for Work license.'

You can also try to access to the the [Google Cloud Support Portal](https://google.secure.force.com/) to signal your problem.

I find this informations in google developer [here](https://developers.google.com/maps/premium/previous-licenses/articles/usage-limits#http403). You can find on this link some solutions like I detail to you and the explanation of your problem.

Answer (score 0):

*"The usage limits were not exceeded"*

Are you sure?  You're loading the `places` library, in which case this applies:

> Google Places API Web Service
>   Default 1,000 free requests per day,
>   increased to 150,000 free requests per day after identity
>   verification.

https://developers.google.com/maps/pricing-and-plans/

See also:

- https://developers.google.com/places/web-service/usage
- https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/places#UsageLimits

Comment: Thank you for answering! After refreshing the page, the map is working well. I've monitored the requests: there are no more than 500. Also, wouldn't have been other error message?

Comment: @AnaDanciu you don't really give any details of what you're doing with the map.  Are you loading the map, then making additional requests to the Places service?

Comment: after loading the map, I draw between 1 and 50 markers. This is the only interaction.

Comment: So why are you including the places library?

Comment: Because this was the link example given from google when adding the map. The project got bigger and since I was sure that the usage limit was not at fault here, didn't mind leave it there. I guess I didn't understand it as much as I thought. I removed the library parameter, and I will be testing in the few weeks to see if that was really the issue. Thank you!